# geom_boxplot as inset in histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm wondering whether it is possible to plot a grouped boxplot as an **inset** into a (larger) histogram with density lines:

Toy data:

```
df <- structure(list(role = c("Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", 
                           "Speaker", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", 
                           "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Recipient", "Speaker", "Speaker", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", 
                           "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", 
                           "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", 
                           "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Speaker", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Recipient", 
                           "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", 
                           "Recipient", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", 
                           "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", 
                           "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", 
                           "Recipient", "Recipient", "Recipient", "Speaker", "Recipient", 
                           "Speaker", "Recipient"), increase_max = c(0.008, 0.118, NA, NA, 
                                                                     NA, 0.209, NA, 0.001, 0.111, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.007, 0.002, 
                                                                     0.006, 0.255, 0.009, NA, 0.004, 0.232, NA, 0.007, 0.004, 0.095, 
                                                                     0.09, NA, 0.002, NA, 0.05, NA, 0.02, 0.045, 0.002, NA, NA, 0.005, 
                                                                     0.012, NA, 0.037, NA, 0.066, NA, 0.019, 0.002, 0.136, NA, 0.003, 
                                                                     NA, 0.128, 0.004, 0.003, NA, NA, NA, 0.03, 0.042, NA, 0.138, 
                                                                     0.139, 0.126, 0.002, NA, 0.005, NA, 0.002, 0.01, 0.001, NA, 0.005, 
                                                                     0.003, NA, NA, 0.002, NA, 0.005, NA, NA, 0.015, 0.007, 0.021, 
                                                                     NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.171, 0.02, 0.036, 0.026, 0.001, 0.033, 
                                                                     0.127, 0.339, 0.075, 0.037, 0.083, NA, 0.041)), class = c("tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                               "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -100L))
```

I can plot the two graphics individually, like so (NB: the data for the histogram is filtered on a number of parameters, the data for the boxplot is **unfiltered**):

Histogram with density lines:

```
df %>% 
  filter(
    !is.na(increase_max) & 
      increase_max >= 0.05 & 
      increase_max <= 0.5) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = increase_max)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(density), fill = role), binwidth = 0.05, position = "identity", alpha = 0.35) +
  geom_density(aes(colour = role)) +
  scale_colour_manual(aesthetics = c("fill", "colour"), values = c("blue", "red")
  )
```

Boxplot:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = increase_max, x = role)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

The output I'm looking for would be similar to this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cowplot` to easily overlay and inset plots. With `hp` as your histogram and `bp` as your box plot:

```r
library(cowplot)

ggdraw() +
  draw_plot(hp) +
  draw_plot(bp, x = .5, y = .65, width = .35, height = .35)
```

[image]

Comment: Very cool. Thank you!